# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Multiple login scenarios

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have a standard template ASP.NET Core web application using VS 2017. By default you can login using username and password and add social media as well: Facebook, Live, Google, etc. No problem here. My problem is how can I add Azure Active Directory as a login functionality so customers can login with username and password or social media and employees can login with Azure AD credentials?

Comment: Did you check the 'azure samples' repo on github? There are plenty of samples for authentication with Azure AD. For example, this one might help you for your scenario: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Comment: @regnauld: I tried some samples from there but it didn't work together with Facebook for some reason. If I removed facebook it worked,if I enable Facebook it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add OpenIdConnect just like you add Facebook. Just be careful that the defaults for AutomaticChallenge are different.

`app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
            {
                AppId = Configuration["facebook:appid"],
                AppSecret = Configuration["facebook:appsecret"]
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                ClientId = Configuration["oidc:clientid"],
                Authority = Configuration["oidc:authority"],
                AutomaticChallenge = false
            });`

Comment: Can you describe more what you mean?